# dataTable.net Server-Side Processing: Not seeming to refresh

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, server-side, datatables

For the site my coworkers and I are working on, we used the dataTable format from www.dataTables.net and we have to use Server-Side processing because of how much the tables grow.  Here's the view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#adminUnassignedTable').dataTable({
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "/Admin/UpdateUnassignedReviewer",
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
  });
</script>

<h2>Unassigned IPBs</h2>
<%
  using (Html.BeginForm("Assign","Admin",FormMethod.Post))
  {
    Html.RenderPartial("AssignmentControls", "Reviewer");
%>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="adminUnassignedTable">
<thead><tr>
<th>IPB Number</th>
<th>IPB Pub Date</th>
<th>Change Number</th>
<th>Change Date</th>
<th>Total # of Parts</th>
<th>Total # of Report Parts</th>
<th>ALC</th>
<th>Date Loaded</th>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>Update</th>
</tr></thread>
<tbody><tr><td colspan="12" class="dataTable_empty">Loading Data From Server</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
<%
  }
%>
```

Here's the sAjaxSource function in the AdminController.cs:

```
public void UpdateUnassignedReviewer()
{
  int[] nArrayStatus = { (int)PTA.Helpers.Constants.State.Queue }
  int nTotalRecordCount = 0;
  string strEcho = "";
  _DisplayRecords = PTA.Helpers.Utility.BeginServerSideProcessing(HttpContext.Request.QueryString, nArrayStates, (int)PTA.Helpers.Constants.Location.Reviewer, ref nTotalRecordCount, ref strEcho);
  string strOutput = "";
  if (_DisplayRecords.Count() <= 0)
  {
    PTA.Helpers.Utility.WriteBlankRecord(ref strOutput, strEcho, 12);
  }
  else
  {
    strOutput += "{\"sEcho\":" + strEcho + ", ";
    strOutput += "\"iTotalRecords\": " + nTotalRecordCount.ToString() + ", ";
    strOutput += "\"iTotalDisplayRecords\": " + nTotalRecordCount.ToString() + ", ";
    strOutput += "\"aaData\": [";
    int nCounter = 0;
    foreach (IPB ipb in _DisplayRecords)
    {
      strOutput += "[ "
      strOutput += "\"";
      strOutput += PTA.Helpers.Utility.CreateDetailsLinkHTML(ipb.ID.ToString(), ipb.IPBName) + "\",";
      strOutput += "\"" + ipb.PubDate + "\",";
      strOutput += "\"" + ipb.Change + "\",";
      strOutput += "\"" + ipb.ChangeDate + "\",";
      strOutput += "\"" + ipb.TotalParts + "\",";
      strOutput += "\"" + ipb.TotalPartsReport + "\",";
      strOutput += "\"" + ipb.ALC + "\",";
      strOutput += "\"" + ipb.DateAdded + "\",";
      strOutput += "\"" + ipb.Priority + "\",";
      strOutput += "\"" + PTA.Helpers.Utility.CreateCheckBoxHTML(ipb.ID.ToString(), nCounter++);
      strOutput += "\""; 
      strOutput += "]";

      if(ipb != _DisplayRecords.Last())
      {
        strOutput += ", ";
      }
    }
  }

  strOutput += "]}";
  Response.Write(strOutput);
}
```

Here's the Assign function

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Assign(string PriorityDropDown, string UserDropDown, string ActionDropDown)
{
  ResetTempData(ref statusID, ref locationID, ref area);

  int  ipb_id = 0,
       action = -1;

  action = Request.Form["ActionDropDown"].ToString() == null || Request.Form["ActionDropDown"].ToString() == "" ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ActionDropDown"]);

  string strUser = "",
         strPriority = "";

  strUser = Request.Form["UserDropDown"];
  strPriority = Request.Form["PriorityDropDown"];

  string[] strTemp = Request.Form.AllKeys;
  foreach(string str in strTemp)
  {
    if(str.Contains("AssignCheck"))
    {
      ipb_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[str]);

      if(action > -1 || (strUser != null || strUser != "") || (strPriority != null || strPriority != ""))
      {
        switch (action)
        {
          case -1:
            Update(ipb_id, strPriority, strUser);
            break;
          case 1:
          case 2:
          case 5:
          case 8:
            Action(ipb_id, action);
            break;
          default: break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return RedirectToAction("AdminView");
}
```

Here's the AdminView function

```
public ActionResult(int? statusID, int? locationID)
{
  if (!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }

  PTA.Modesl.DataFactory factory = new DataFactory();
  if(statusID == null)
  {
    statusID = (int)PTA.Helpers.Constants.State.Queue;
    ViewData["status"] = statusID;
  }

  if(locationID == null)
  {
    locationID = (int)PTA.Helpers.Constants.Location.Reviewer;
    ViewData["location"] = locationID;
  }

  TempData["pageStatus"] = statusID;
  TempData["pageLocation"] = locationID;
  TempData["Area"] = Request.QueryString["Area"]?? "Unassigned";

  return View();
}
```

Also, as a note, my dev machine is not the same as my network machine.  So I can't copy and paste, I also can't use thumb drives.  Therefore, I have to manually type everything.  So if you see some typos, just ask me and I'll let you know if it's correct.  Also, there are two actions you may ask to see, I just didn't type them just because of how long it took to type everything else.  Action and Assign.  If you want/need to see them, let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: StringBuilder could be your friend for some of that codebehind code,,

Comment: lol. I know it's not pretty. My coworkers and I touch it all at different times. I'm a format stickler and a "one-liner" whenever I can. Just so long as the line isn't 500 characters. I abuse the hell out of ternary statements.  They explained it to me as they like to have as many breakpoints as possible.  Bah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol.  The answer is use the newest version.  I was using 1.6.7 when I should have been using 1.7.0.  It now works fine.